# Django - Reading Excel File

Tags: python, django

- User will upload the Excel file from client machine
- Retrieve all the available sheets and need to show in the drop down list
- User has to choose the specific sheet
- Need to send an email for each available row in that particular sheet.

I just explored openpyxl and planning to use the same. I believe that it may consume lot of memory. Any best practice suggestions to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your lucky there is a website dedicated to your plight 
http://www.python-excel.org/